# How to use Group By in SOQL ? Error : Return value must be of type: List<pba_listingobj__c>

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, query

[image: Query Results]

```
@RemoteAction
global static List<pba_listingobj__c> getAccountstages(String namejs) 
{   
 return [SELECT sales_stage__c FROM pba_listingobj__c where Account_lookup__r.Name=:namejs GROUP BY sales_stage__c];        
}
```

Where `Account_lookup__c` is Lookup to `Account`.

Field name: Account_lookup__c

How to have unique Stages (`sales_stage__c`)(values can be : Closed Won, Prospect)?

Records:

1. Prospect
2. Closed Won
3. Closed Won
4. Closed Won

Desired Output: As shown in the above screenshot.

1. Prospect
2. Closed Won

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `GROUP BY` clause, the query returns `List<AggregateResult>`.

```
@RemoteAction
global static List<AggregateResult> getAccountStages(String name)
{
    // same query
}
```

You may wish to simply return a `List<String>`, depending on how you consume this data downstream.

```
@RemoteAction
global static List<String> getAccountStages(String name)
{
    List<String> stages = new List<String>();
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : [/*query*/])
        stages.add((String)aggregate.get('Sales_Stage__c'));
    return stages;
}
```